# Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'edit'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

I'm doing this tutorial from SmashingMagazine (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/) and I keep hitting this error when I try to use a button calling a custom action:

> Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'edit'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the 
>   action to bubble.

---

`user.js` controller:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        edit: function(){
            this.transitionToRoute('user.edit');
        }
    }
});
```

`user.hbs` view:

```
<div class="user-profile">
    <button {{action "edit"}}>Edit</button>
    <!--<img {{bind-attr src="avatarUrl"}} alt="User's avatar" />-->
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <span>{{email}}</span>
    <p>{{bio}}</p>
    <span>Created {{creationDate}}</span>
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

`user\edit.hbs` view:

```
<div class="user-edit">
  <label>Choose user avatar</label>
  {{input value=avatarUrl}}

  <label>User name</label>
  {{input value=name}}

  <label>User email</label>
  {{input value=email}}

  <label>User short bio</label>
  {{textarea value=bio}}
</div>
```

---

All the rest is working fine. I can display my user list and invidual users.

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess it's not using the controller.  You can log the controller creation, `var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
}); `

Comment: @kingpin2k This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/rdYbRSg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. I accidently overwrited my `user.js` route file. Replaced the content with:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) { 
        return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
    }
});
```

Sorry for bothering, and thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but for a different reason. There are demo videos that use the following code.

```
App.FileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    edit: function () {
        this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    done: function () {
        this.set('isEditing', false);
    }
});
```

If you take a look at this link from the [EmberJs website](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/toggle-todo-editing-state/) you will see that you need to wrap your methods in an `actions` property for it to work.

```
App.FileController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {                            //<------
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },
        done: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        }                                 //<------
    }
});
```

I hope I saved you some time.